# Integrating python webapp with some jar files

Tags: java, python

Hi I have few jar files which are few calculations compiled into jar files. I have a python web app which is supposed to interact with these jar files and get me the data. I have heard that it can be done using the java bridge. Can someone let me know how this could be done or at least point me to the right link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [jython](http://www.jython.org/).You can interact back and forth between python and java using jython.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run the jar files in a subprocess and use PIPE for IO (or temp files). This works pretty well for us (we are generating PDF from our Django app with flying saucer and iText)